# How do I detect if the mouse is pressed, not just clicked

Tags: c++

The program must detect when the keys WASD are pressed, but only while the left button is pressed.

I was trying this code, but it only writes when I click.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
 
using namespace std;

int KeyPressed(int key){
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000 != 0);
}
 
int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    while (true){
        if(KeyPressed(VK_LBUTTON)){

            input.ki.wVk = 0x57;    //W
            input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

            input.ki.wVk = 0x41;    //A
            input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

            input.ki.wVk = 0x53;    //S
            input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

            input.ki.wVk = 0x44;    //D
            input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arthur. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question. I hope it still reflects the original intent of your question. You can always re-edit it if it doesn't

Comment: Due to priority issues, you need to modify it to `return ((GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0);`

Comment: It worked @ZhuSong-MSFT thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not simulating the WASD keys being released when you release the mouse button.

Also, calling `SendInput()` with `cInputs=1` is (almost always) a bug.  When sending multiple events together, use an array of multiple `INPUT`s.  This avoids any race condition where other events might otherwise get interweaved in between your simulated events.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int KeyPressed(int key){
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000 != 0);
}
 
int main()
{
    INPUT inputs[4] = {};
    bool mouseIsDown = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        inputs[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[i].ki.wScan = 0;
        inputs[i].ki.time = 0;
        inputs[i].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    }

    inputs[0].ki.wVk = 0x57;    //W
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = 0x41;    //A
    inputs[2].ki.wVk = 0x53;    //S
    inputs[3].ki.wVk = 0x44;    //D

    while (true) {
        if (KeyPressed(VK_LBUTTON)) {
            if (!mouseIsDown){
                mouseIsDown = true;

                for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    inputs[i].ki.dwFlags = 0;
                }

                SendInput(4, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
            }
        }
        else if (mouseIsDown) {
            mouseIsDown = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                inputs[i].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            }

            SendInput(4, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        }

        Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It almost worked, the problem is that it is releasing the WASD keys before I release the mouse1. And sometimes it doesn't anything.

Comment: "*it is releasing the WASD keys before I release the mouse1*" - that is simply not possible, since the check for `KeyPressed(VK_LBUTTON)` is ensuring the mouse has to already be in a released state before the code can then issue its `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` events. Make sure something else on your machine is not simulating its own events for the WASD keys. "*And sometimes it doesn't anything*" - then you are going to have to debug the code to find out why

Comment: But you helped me alot, thanks for that. I really appreciate it, but it is not working for what im looking for. That's prob my fault.